# CVE vulnerable apps repository

Tags: cve, git

According to your experience, do you know if a repository of vulnerable apps indexed by CVE exists? 
Exploit-DB offers vulnerable apps, i.e. for:

```
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/46962
```

it is possible to install the vulnerable app:

```
https://www.exploit-db.com/apps/f02234bb10ee2657aacdd5ac9b38c134-DVDXPlayerSetup.exe
```

I wondered if exists some standardized/non-standardized way to obtain vulnerable packages indexed by CVE / OVAL / CPE / other.

Comment: Hi @gx1, welcome to the site! Just to double check - you want the actual files themselves?

Comment: Hi @Cowthulhu , thank you for the welcome! Yes, an index of absolute url with vulnerable applications. I think about a structure like: 

`{VULN_APP_ID: 2, CVE_ID: 333,    
 vulnerable_app_url:https://url//vulnerable.zip}`.

Comment: An API-rest that returns this kind of information could be very useful to test vulnerabilities.  
It could be very useful to have a standard for the installation steps, but I think that this is a very complex goal...

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find X?" or "what product/service does X?" is off topic as the list of potential answers could be endless.

Comment: I don't know if you've thought of it, but Github can be used this way.